# How to retrieve radiobutton selected value on asp: button click in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, onclick, radio-button

I have an update page with radiobutton "Alternate Addresses".
If the radiobutton has "Yes" value, There would be altenate addresses for client.
If radiobutton has "No" value, there won't be any alternate addresses.
In update page, if supplier changes radiobutton value from `"Yes" to "No"` and clicks `asp:Button "Update"`, all alternate addresses will be deleted.

I want to show a confirm messagebox on Update button click. But i am not being able to retrieve radiobutton selected value in javascript.

```
 var list = document.getElementById("radios"); //Client ID of the radiolist  
var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("input");  
var selected;  
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
{       
if (inputs[i].checked)
 {           
selected = inputs[i];           
break;        
}
```

This code works fine with html buttons. But I want code for `asp:Button onClientClick.` Please Help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net 4, if so is your ClientIdMode set to static? If not then probably you will have to resolve the client id by itself. Note that the ID of server control will not be same as it;s client id. Refer this for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can attach javascript from code behind as well like.

```
ASPNET_Server_Control.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return yourJSFunction();")
```

You should make sure you return false in asp button, if you dont want a post back to happen.